# Can I add multiple xbox live gold cards to my account?

Tags: xbox-network

I received two 12 month xbox live gold cards for Christmas.  Can I add both to my Microsoft account now, and will it be good for 24 months?

Answer (score 1):

Yes

It'll simply end up with 24 months on your account. If you log into your account online however it may say it's only active for 12 months, however once that 12 months finishes, the next card will automatically activate.

The only time this doesn't work is when you get '24 hour' or some other short access passes which come free with some games, these generally don't 'queue up' like normal xbox live access codes.